# Как правильно указать 'default' для ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

```
class vedModel(models.Model):

    # прикрепит к базовому объекту профиля
    base_id = models.ForeignKey('account.profileModel', on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT, default = 'account.profileModel.objects.get(login="123")')
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: ved
Running migrations:
  Applying ved.0003_auto_20200902_1939...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'account.profileModel.objects.get(login="123")'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 245, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 106, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 328, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 189, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 303, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 971, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 823, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2388, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\ledo\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1778, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'account.profileModel.objects.get(login="123")'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так работает

```
base_id = models.ForeignKey('account.profileModel', default = profileModel.objects.get(login='admin').id, on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT)
```